# Android ImageView center in RelativeLayout getY() return 0

Tags: android

```
         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/book_mark"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            custom:layoutBackground="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/book_mark_image"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_bookmark"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

My layout xml above. when I call imageview.getY() ,I get 0 for result. When I run this application, ImageView actually center in RelativeLayout. but getY() return 0. According to the size of layout, the distance of imageView to relativeLayout should be 9dp, so getY() should return (9dp -> px). Anyone knows what happened?

Comment: Are you calling getY() on any event or in onCreate() Directly?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out , I am calling getY() before being drawn

Answer (score 0):

please first make sure your image visibility is not gone

else this is because most probably you are calling getY() in on create or on resume 
the problem is that your image is not yet loaded to know the exact position of image view now you can use observer

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = image1.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                        //now get width or position 

                        //and don't forget to remove listener
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            image1.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        else
                            image1.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
```